# How would I support different screen sizes, Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get it so that my buttons and UI will resize with the screen size that the game is playing in.

How would I do this?

What I have on my canvas:

[image: Canvas]

Comment: Google ) IF you use unit UI apply proper setting to Canvas.

Comment: Do you want me to google that? or..

Comment: You will need to familiarize yourself with how the ui system works.  Understanding how anchors work is absolutely critical.  [Designing UI for Multiple Resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)  There is a setting on the canvas scaler `UI Scale Mode`, switch this to `Scale with Screen Size`

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all, you have to select on hierarchy the canvas that you want to resize depending the screen size. Then in the inspector you will go to "Canvas scaler" and in UI scale mode you select "Scale with screen size"[image]

[image]

Comment: In my question, I have added an image to what I've got on the canvas.